# COUNT / MAX (COUNT) not working in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm not much used to SQL, but on my own I've been able to run this code:

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  COUNT(event_name) AS count,
  COUNT(event_name) / SUM(COUNT(event_name)) OVER () * 100 AS event_percent
FROM `table_1`
WHERE
  event_name IN ('session_start', 'view_item', 'select_item', 'add_to_cart', 'remove_from_cart', 'begin_checkout', 'purchase' )
GROUP BY
  event_name
ORDER BY
  count DESC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do1Jg.png)

What I'd like to achive is the percentatge of each COUNT divided by the MAX COUNT. Example: purchase / session_start (22 / 1258)

If anyone can help.. I've tried some things but none worked

Answer (score 0):

I guess a CTE would work

```sql
WITH prep AS (
SELECT
  event_name,
  COUNT(event_name) AS cnt,
  COUNT(event_name) / SUM(COUNT(event_name)) OVER () * 100 AS event_percent
FROM `table_1`
WHERE
  event_name IN ('session_start', 'view_item', 'select_item', 'add_to_cart', 'remove_from_cart', 'begin_checkout', 'purchase' )
GROUP BY
  event_name
ORDER BY
  count DESC
)

SELECT
 *,
 cnt / max(cnt) over()  
FROM
  prep
```

Comment: Oh! yeah it worked. I thought CTE only worked with two temporary tables, not just one. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Cool :) Feel free to accept the answer ;)